# What are the equivalent architecture of alphanumeric numbers in Debian?

Tags: debian, architecture

On the Debian [website](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/data/releases), I found a list of the releases of Debian associate with alphanumerical architectures. Do you know to what those architectures numbers and letters stand for?

[image: ss #1]

Comment: You should bring the example you give into your question, links can change sometime and it makes your question strange. also in my opinion it just mean debian guys doesn't know there alphabet and how to count to 9

Comment: The gaps are obviously for architectures that are no longer being offered.

Answer (score 4):

I asked on #debian-mentors, and Paul Wise pointed me to a bug report. The entries you see are caused by a bug. See the Debian bug report [http://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/data/releases broken](https://bugs.debian.org/610222).

```
07:05 < pabs> faheem: https://bugs.debian.org/610222
07:06 < pabs> faheem: I guess patches would be welcome
07:15 < ats> faheem: so my first guess was that it was a Plan 9-style code,   
             but no, it's just a bug
07:16 < ats> I think what's happening is that it's taking a list of          
             architectures along the lines of "i386,armhf,kfreebsd-i386" and   
             splitting it by characters rather than on ,
07:16 < ats> so that's actually a list of all the characters that are used in 
             Debian architecture names ;-)
07:17 < ats> line 407-ish in http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/secure-
             testing/lib/python/security_db.py?view=markup suggests that it        
             does split on , first, though, so presumably that's not getting 
             used properly when fetching the arch field from the database...
```

Note. Patches welcome. :-)

Comment: Is there a way to turn the url into a link?

Comment: not inside a code block I'm afraid...